# Class with generic type and generic list

Tags: c#, class, generics, radix, derived

I want to have a list of custom objects with a "generic" type in one of the properties.

```
public class Tag
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }

    public ??? value {get;set;}

}
```

The "value" can be int,double,string or bool.

How can I make a "generic" list of my custom Tag class?

```
public list<Tag> t;
```

I have looked the "generic" collections and classes, but the problem, is that if I made

```
class Tag<T>{}
```

I can not do:

```
List<Tag<T>> list = new List<Tag<T>>();
list.add(new Tag<int>());
list.add(new Tag<double>());
```

I have tried using interfaces, base classes ... I don't know where to look

Some ideas? help?

Thank  you so much.

Comment: What language is the question about? TIA.

Comment: oh sorry, it is C#

Comment: „*oh sorry, it is C#*“ — [*FTFY*](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/4956551) :)

Comment: Why are you putting objects of different types in the same list? How do you expect to use those exactly?

Answer (score 1):

A common approach would be to make an interface or base class.

```
public interface ITag
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    int Id { get; set; }

    object Value { get; }
    Type ValueType { get; }
}
```

Then `Tag` can be generic:

```
public class Tag<T> : ITag
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public T Value { get; set; }

    object ITag.Value => this.Value;
    Type ITag.ValueType => typeof(T);
}
```

Now you can do this:

```
List<ITag> list = new List<ITag>();
list.Add(new Tag<int>());
list.Add(new Tag<double>());
```

The question is still why?

Comment: Hi, thanks for all the answers. I need this because, my application is connected to a PLC (an external device), and this PLC has different data types, ushort, int, bool, double... I wanted only 1 list of this elements. I have tried the solution that you proposed, the problem is that when I get one element I need to do some casts and I don't want this. I think maybe I need to find another design to solve this.

Comment: @Sined - There is no way to solve this without casting. Perhaps you can explain what you needed to do and we could help with that?

Comment: Hi, what I want is to not have 500 objects declared ( TagInt tag1 = new...., TagDouble tag2 = new....) I want to create a list of Tag objects and make some methods to get a specific Tag.

Comment: @Sined - Which is fine. LINQ can do that easily. What's the issue?

Comment: I want to have a generic class "Tag", in which I want to have a property with the type of the data that I read from the PLC (bool, int, double...) this part is easy and I have it, and then I want to have a list of Tag. I want this to access the list and get and set the values of this list. The problem? I can create a generic class, but I can not create "List<Tag<T>> mylist...." and if I put the type T e.g: int, all the objects should be int so I can add to the list and this is not what I want, I want to have only one list.

Comment: @Sined - So, if you start with a `List<ITag> list` you can do `.OfType<Tag<int>>()` to get a sequence of all the `Tag<int>` tags. Does that work for you?